# change scrollbar color dynamically in angular 7

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I want to change the scrollbar color dynamically based on the selection and color code coming from API.

I try to use ngClass directive but colors are dynamically allocated based on API so it won't help me.

HTML code

```
<div class="table-responsive"
      [ngClass]="{'scbio': currentSubject === 'BIO'}">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.scbio::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f5b58f;
}

.scbio::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #cc7b50;
}
```

Need to change background based on API color code. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use the [ngClass]="colorChooser()" attribute and then in your ts file define that method..

example:

```
colorChooser() { /* your logic here */}
```